# calculating and displaying numbers in java

Tags: java, swing, bigdecimal

I have the following code....

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_price.getText());
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_quantity.getText());

double result = num1*num2;
textArea_result.setText(
    new BigDecimal(textArea_price.getText())
        .multiply(new BigDecimal(textArea_quantity.getText())).toString());
```

Everytime a button is clicked  the numbers in textArea_price and textArea_quantity is multiplied and displayed in  textArea_result. I want the value in  textArea_result to be added onto the result of the multiplication of the two textareas rather than resetting the value in  textArea_result every time the button is clicked...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You could save the value in textArea_result before doing the setText part and then add it before/after the toString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Java but wouldn't it be this?

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_price.getText());

double num2 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_quantity.getText());

double oldResult = 0;
String result = textArea_result.getText();
if (result  != "")
    oldResult = Double.parseDouble(result);

double result = oldResult + num1 * num2;
textArea_result.setText(Double.toString(result));
```

If you really want to avoid if statements try this, but it is just syntactical sugar:

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_price.getText());

double num2 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_quantity.getText());

String result = textArea_result.getText();
double oldResult = (result == "") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(result);

double result = oldResult + num1 * num2;
textArea_result.setText(Double.toString(result));
```

Comment: Almost.. Just replace the last line with: textArea_result.setText(Double.toString(result));

Comment: Like so?  Hey, I like Java.  Its kinda geeky with its cute little lowercase method names. :)  But what if textArea_result isn't a number?  Like the initial time the button is pressed.  Is it empty?

Comment: @Jordan I am getting this error message Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: @Jordan  I am sure there is a way to do it without using the if statement... I am getting the same error with everything I try... Btw I am new to Java myself doing some self learning :)

Comment: Why are you trying to do it without the if statement?  The exception you are getting is because you are trying to parse an empty string.  You can't parse an empty string.  You have to check it to make sure it isn't empty before you parse it.

Comment: The other two fields already has if statement to check that they are not empty...

Comment: @Jordan no matter what i try it still giving me the same error - CShellExt::CShellException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: @Jordan It seems to work now. Both codes you have provided works only I have set the initial values of the textArea_result to zero, so basically it has zero as an initial value (its not empty)..

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_price.getText());
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(textArea_quantity.getText());
double oldres = Double.parseDouble(textArea_result.getText());

double result = oldres + num1*num2;
textArea_result.setText(Double.toString(result));
```

Or:

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(textArea_price.getText());
BigDecimal quantity = new BigDecimal(textArea_quantity.getText());
BigDecimal oldTotal = new BigDecimal(textArea_result.getText());

BigDecimal total = price.multiply(quantity).add(oldTotal);
textArea_result.setText(total.toString());
```